# AVSampleBufferDisplayLayer not rendering frames anymore in iOS10

Tags: avfoundation, calayer, ios10

The following setup has been working on all recent iOS versions until iOS10:

I am using `AVSampleBufferDisplayLayer` to render raw frames from a custom source.

I have a pixel buffer pool set up using `CVPixelBufferPoolCreate`, and have the `kCVPixelBufferIOSurfacePropertiesKey` set to `@{}` as instructed by Apple.

I use `CVPixelBufferPoolCreatePixelBuffer` to obtain a pixel buffer from the pool and then copy my data to the buffer by using `CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress` and `CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress`.

My raw frames use the NV12 format `kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarVideoRange`.

Here is a code snippet showing how I convert the pixel buffer to a `CMSampleBufferRef` and enqueue it to the display layer:

```
  CMSampleTimingInfo sampleTimeinfo{
      CMTimeMake(duration.count(), kOneSecond.count()),
      kCMTimeInvalid,
      kCMTimeInvalid};

  CMFormatDescriptionRef formatDescription = nullptr;
  CMVideoFormatDescriptionCreateForImageBuffer(nullptr, pixelBuffer, &formatDescription);

  CMSampleBufferRef sampleBuffer = nullptr;
  CMSampleBufferCreateForImageBuffer(
          nullptr, pixelBuffer, true, nullptr, nullptr, formatDescription, &sampleTimeinfo, &sampleBuffer));


  CFArrayRef attachmentsArray = CMSampleBufferGetSampleAttachmentsArray(sampleBuffer, YES);
  const CFIndex numElementsInArray = CFArrayGetCount(attachmentsArray);

  for (CFIndex i = 0; i < numElementsInArray; ++i) {
    CFMutableDictionaryRef attachments = (CFMutableDictionaryRef)CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(attachmentsArray, i);
    CFDictionarySetValue(attachments, kCMSampleAttachmentKey_DisplayImmediately, kCFBooleanTrue);
  }

  if ([avfDisplayLayer_ isReadyForMoreMediaData]) {
    [avfDisplayLayer_ enqueueSampleBuffer:sampleBuffer];
  }

  CFRelease(sampleBuffer);
  CFRelease(formatDescription);
```

`pixelBuffer` is of type `CVPixelBufferRef`, and `avfDisplayLayer_` `AVSampleBufferDisplayLayer`.

This next snippet shows how I construct the display layer:

```
  avfDisplayLayer_ = [[AVSampleBufferDisplayLayer alloc] init];
  avfDisplayLayer_.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;
```

I am not getting any warning or error messages, the display layer status does not indicate a failure and `isReadyForMoreMediaData` is returning true.

The problem is that my frames do not show on the screen. I have also set a background color on the display layer, just to make sure the layer is composited correctly (which it is).

Something must have changed in iOS10 with regards to the AVSampleBufferDisplayLayer, but I am unable to figure out what it is.

Comment: We are seeing this in our application as well, so I submitted a bug report to Apple and copied the info to OpenRadar: https://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=5001147395866624

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that with iOS10, the values for CMSampleTimingInfo are apparently parsed more stringently.

The above code was changed to the following to make rendering work correctly once more:

```
  CMSampleTimingInfo sampleTimeinfo{
      CMTimeMake(duration.count(), kOneSecond.count()),
      kCMTimeZero,
      kCMTimeInvalid};
```

Please note the `kCMTimeZero` for the `presentationTimeStamp` field.

@Sterling Archer: You may want to give this a try to see if it addresses your problem as well.

Comment: Indeed this did resolve our issue as well. We don't necessarily have a constant frame rate, so our `CMSampleTimingInfo` struct has `kCMTimeIndefinite` for the `duration` member. Thanks for following up!

Comment: This does appear to be resolved in iOS 10 Beta 4 [14A5322e]. `kCMTimeInvalid` as `presentationTimeStamp` no longer breaks rendering with `kCMSampleAttachmentKey_DisplayImmediately` as far as I can tell.